# Setting value for CompletableFuture within a lambda

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```java
public CompletableFuture<Object> send(String message) {
    CompletableFuture<Object> response =  new CompletableFuture<>();
    KafkaProducerRecord<String, String> record = ...
    KafkaProducer producer = ...
    producer.write(record, done -> {
        if(done.succeeded()) {
            Object o = ...
            response.complete(...);
        }
        else {
            Object o = ...
            response.complete(...);
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

The problem is that while `response.complete()` is being called and passed the correct value whether `done.succeeded()` is true or false, `response.result` is always being returned as null. `response.result` is only set if `response.complete()` is called outside the lambda expression before returning.

In the calling method I have tried the following:

```
CompletableFuture<IResponse> resp = this.send(message);
try {
  System.out.println(resp.get());
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this just hangs. The same is true when wrapping the wrapping the `CompletableFuture` in an `Observable` and then doing `subscribe()` on the Observable, as follows:

```
Observable.fromFuture(this.send(message)).subscribe(i -> {});
```

Can anyone assist, thanks.

Comment: How is this related to RxJava? Also this is likely a coding mistake you didn't make when posting the code snippet.

Comment: `response` in the code you show cannot be null because you set it to `new ...` and it is effectively final (otherwise the lambda would not compile).

Comment: My bad - it is the result value in the CompletableFuture which is null. Have corrected the question.

Comment: When is it null? Can you show the code where you access the result and get null?

Comment: on the final line 'return response', it shows result to be an instance of CompletableFuture, which has a result member which is null.

Comment: That is to be expected, the method is not yet completed in the CompletableFuture. Until it does it will remain null. The code calling the method should use the get() method to get the result. This will block the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `response.result` is always being returned as null

How did you get access to that field? It is an internal field that stores the result once it has been computed.

To get the result you need to call `get()` which will block until the result is ready, or `isDone()` to check if it is ready.

Comment: Thanks. Have tried both get() on the CompletableFuture,  and wrapping the CompletableFuture  in an Observable, and then doing subscribe() on the Observable. However, both approaches hang the system - even though the debugger shows that complete() has been called on the CompletableFuture. Have updated the question to show this.

Comment: `get()` will block, but what do you mean by "the system hangs" with the Observable?

Comment: Once the debugger hits subscribe, the applications hangs

Comment: That may be a problem with the debugger more than the application. Are you sure it is not paused by some breakpoint? Note that there are multiple threads involved now.